# PHP displaying individual tables

Tags: php, html-table

At the moment my produces results from a database and then inserts all of the results into one HTML table.

Is there any way that it would be possible so that for each result returned it created an individual HTML table (opposed to all of the results going into one HTML table)

My code:

```
<table class=\"board\" width='100%' border='0' align='center' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1'> 
");
            $type = $_GET["type"];
            if ($type == "" || $type == "request") {
                $get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM request WHERE type='Request' AND deleted != 'yes' ORDER BY id DESC");
            } else {
                if ($type == "shoutout") {
                    $get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM request WHERE type='Shoutout' AND deleted != 'yes' ORDER BY id DESC");
                } else {
                    if ($type == "competition") {
                        $get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM request WHERE type='Competition' AND deleted != 'yes' ORDER BY id DESC");
                    } else {
                        if($type == "all") {
                            $get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM request WHERE deleted != 'yes' ORDER BY id DESC");                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            $num = @mysql_num_rows($get);
            if ($num == 0) {
                echo ("<div class=\"board\"><center><font color=\"red\">There aren't any requests in this category!<br />
Why not ask listeners to send in their requests?</font></center></div>");
            } else {
                while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($get)) {
                    echo " 
 <tr>
    <td><font face=\"verdana\" size=\"1\"><b>User</b></td>
    <td><font face=\"verdana\" size=\"1\"><b>$r[habboname]</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><font face=\"verdana\" size=\"1\"><b>Date</b></td>
    <td><font face=\"verdana\" size=\"1\">$r[date]</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><font face=\"verdana\" size=\"1\"><b>IP</b></td>
    <td><font face=\"verdana\" size=\"1\">$r[ip]</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><font face=\"verdana\" size=\"1\"><b>Message</b></td>
    <td><font face=\"verdana\" size=\"1\">$r[message]</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><font face=\"verdana\" size=\"1\"><b>Type</b></td>
    <td><font face=\"verdana\" size=\"1\">$r[type]</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <!--  <td><font face=\"verdana\" size=\"1\"><b>Refferer</b></td>
    <td><font face=\"verdana\" size=\"1\">"; 
    if($r[refferer] == 1){ echo "Site.com</td>"; } else { echo "Site1.com</td>"; } 

echo "--></tr>
  <tr>
    <td><font face=\"verdana\" size=\"1\"><b>Commands</b></td>
    <td><a href=\"vrequest.php?id=$r[id]\"><font face=\"verdana\" size=\"1\">Delete</a> - <a href=\"mode.php?ban=1&id=$r[id]&ip=$r[ip]&message=$r[message]\">Ban</a> - <!--<a href=\"site_alert.php?type=user&ip=" . $r["ip"] . "\">Alert</a>--><a href=\"lotw.php\">Nominate LoTW</a></font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
";
                    $id = htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']);
                    $delete = mysql_query("UPDATE request SET deleted = 'yes' WHERE id = '$id'");
                }
                echo ("</table></div>");
            }
            break;
        case 'delete':
```

Comment: It looks like you're just learning so I wanted to offer a few pointers. I re-wrote your query generating section so that its more readable. http://pastebin.com/81Nr1WiP . Also, your font tags are not closed, which is an error. More importantly, since your just starting and you're developing your habits, you should try to start learning CSS. Font tags should not be used at all. You should also avoid the width, border, align attributes on your table unless they are needed to support old browsers. Best of luck!

Comment: Why don't you use a style sheet instead of manually setting the font?

Comment: Furthermore, instead of having your deleted field be a string ('yes', 'no'), you will get better performance out of an int (1, 0) that is indexed.

Comment: If you don't use Andy's `switch` example, at least use `else if {}` when assigning `$type`. Not `else { if {} }`.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to create as many tables as there are returned rows, just put the opening `<table>` into the `while`'s beginning and the closing `</table>` to the end of `while`. However, I don't understand why this would be desired. Do you really want to create many tables with just one row? It kind of defeats the purpose of a table. Make a list or use `span`'s or anything else than tables instead.

```
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($get)) {
echo "<table class=\"board\">
<tr>
  <td><b>User</b></td>
  <td><b>$r[habboname]</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><b>Date</b></td>
  <td>$r[date]</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td><b>IP</b></td>
  <td>$r[ip]</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td><b>Message</b></td>
  <td>$r[message]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><b>Type</b></td>
  <td>$r[type]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <!--  <td><b>Refferer</b></td>
  <td>"; 

if($r[refferer] == 1){ echo "Site.com</td>"; } else { echo "Site1.com</td>"; } 

echo "--></tr>
<tr>
  <td><b>Commands</b></td>
  <td><a href=\"vrequest.php?id=$r[id]\">Delete</a> - <a href=\"mode.php?ban=1&id=$r[id]&ip=$r[ip]&message=$r[message]\">Ban</a> - <!--<a href=\"site_alert.php?type=user&ip=" . $r["ip"] . "\">Alert</a>--><a href=\"lotw.php\">Nominate LoTW</a></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>";

$id = htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']);
$delete = mysql_query("UPDATE request SET deleted = 'yes' WHERE id = '$id'");
}

echo "</div>"; //remove () after echo
```

---

Update. One another thing. Please don't use inline styling. You have `table class="board"` so you already probably know the power of CSS.

Second update. I removed `<font ...>` tags. Use CSS for example like this:

```
table.board{
  width:100%;
  border:0;
  align:center;
  cellpadding:1;
  cellspacing:1;
}

table.board td{
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

CSS saves a lot of trouble when you want to change styling. And trust me, there will be a time when you want to change it (or your boss want's to bling-bling the site...).

Answer (score 0):

ZZ-bb is absolutely right and as a hint try to put if/else construction in mysql - it will move faster or optimize it in php, like:

```
$get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM request WHERE " . ($type == 'all' ? 'type = 1' : 'type = ucfirst($type)' ) . " AND deleted != 'yes' ORDER BY id DESC");
```